# Como ler uma struct dentro de outra com Json.Net?

Tags: c#, json.net

Preciso que o programa leia essa informação:

> {"kiseryota":{"id":15031780,"name":"Kise Ryota","profileIconId":1374,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1475089675000}}

Estou fazendo assim:
Estrutura:

```
public struct SummonerInfo0
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProfileIconId { get; set; }
    public long RevisionDate { get; set; }
    public long Level { get; set; }
}
```

Declarando um objeto da estrutura:

```
private SummonerInfo0 _summonerInfo0;
```

Recebendo a string:

```
_jsonSummonerInfo0 = e.Result;
```

Deserializando (não sei como se escreve):

```
_summonerInfo0 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SummonerInfo0>(_jsonSummonerInfo0);
```

O problema é que aparentemente da forma que eu recebo a informação, parece uma estrutura dentro da outra, eu tentei colocar uma dentro da outra mas não funcionou, dai já não sei oque fazer :/

Comment: Vai passar diretamente ou através de parametros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse `JSON` possui um chave, então crie mais uma `struct` da seguinte forma:

```
public struct Layout
{
    public SummonerInfo0 kiseryota { get; set; }
} 

public struct SummonerInfo0
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("profileIconId")]
    public int ProfileIconId { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("revisionDate")]
    public long RevisionDate { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("level")]
    public long Level { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Utilizando:**

```
string json = "{\"kiseryota\":{\"id\":15031780,\"name\":\"Kise Ryota\",\"profileIconId\":1374,\"summonerLevel\":30,\"revisionDate\":1475089675000}}";
Layout resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Layout>(json);
SummonerInfo0 summonerInfo0 = resultado.kiseryota;
```

***Observação:*** na `struct SummonerInfo0` foi decorada para que ele reconheça corretamente as propriedades.

***Forma lendo cada token:***

```
string json = "{\"kiseryota\":{\"id\":15031780,\"name\":\"Kise Ryota\",\"profileIconId\":1374,\"summonerLevel\":30,\"revisionDate\":1475089675000}}";
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
SummonerInfo0 c = new SummonerInfo0();
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
    {
        reader.Read();
        var res = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        var jobj = JObject.Parse(res.ToString());
        c.Id = jobj.SelectToken("id") != null ? jobj.SelectToken("id").Value<long>() : 0;
        c.Name = jobj.SelectToken("name") != null ? jobj.SelectToken("name").Value<string>() : string.Empty;
        c.ProfileIconId = jobj.SelectToken("profileIconId") != null ? jobj.SelectToken("profileIconId").Value<int>() : 0;
        c.RevisionDate = jobj.SelectToken("revisionDate") != null ? jobj.SelectToken("revisionDate").Value<long>() : 0;
        c.Level = jobj.SelectToken("level") != null ? jobj.SelectToken("level").Value<long>() : 0;
    }
}
reader.Close();

c; // variavel preenchida!
```

Comment: Ei, no caso esse primeiro nome nem sempre vai ser kiseryota, é variante, então como proceder?

Comment: Faça então manual! que se tiver qualquer tipo de propriedade e o resto do layout for igual vai funcionar

Comment: Manual você diz... Remover essa parte com um string.Remove?

Comment: Não desculpa lendo cada token desse json.